# Postgres Combine Select and insert in one Query

Tags: postgresql

pardon for this silly question, seems its to late to think clear.

How can I combine these two Queries in PostgreSQL to one. That "NewUserAge" gets insert into field age from query two?

```
SELECT max(age+1) as NewUserAge 
  FROM mytable;


INSERT INTO 
    mytable (age,name) 
VALUES
    (11,'Bert');
```

Thanks for your help,

tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (age,name) 
SELECT  max(age) + 1, 'Bert'
FROM myTable
```